# How to cast a list of specific type to a list of generic type in c#

Tags: c#, list, generics, casting

I have the list which i would like to map to List.
However, there is no compiler error, but at runtime result is coming as null.
Getting a generic `List<T>` will help me make my code generic and reuse for different objects.

```
private static List<T> GetIndexData(DataAdapter dataAdapter)
{
  Type type = typeof(T);
  List<T> result = new List<T>();

  if (typeof(Category).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
  {
    var output = ItemStoreDataManager.GetAllCategoryNames(dataAdapter);                
    result = output as List<T>;                    
  }
  return result;
}
```

Above code **result** is coming as null.

```
internal static List<Category> GetAllCategoryNames(DataAdapter dataAdapter)
{
  List<Category> result = new List<Category>();

  ...........
  return result;
}
```

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: If the types `T` and `U` are assigment compatible, it does not automatically mean that `List<T>` and `List<U>` are assignment compatible as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error is in the following line of code:

```
result = output as List<T>;
```

C# won't let you cast a `List<TSomething>` to `List<TSomethingElse>` using the [`as`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx) operator. You're seeing a `null` value for the reasons specified in MSDN...

> The as operator is like a cast operation. However, if the conversion is not possible, as returns null instead of raising an exception.
>
> Note that the as operator only performs reference conversions and boxing conversions. The as operator cannot perform other conversions, such as user-defined conversions, which should instead be performed by using cast expressions.

Your options are either to build up your new list item-by-item using a `foreach` loop, or use [`Enumerable.Cast`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx) (from `System.Linq`) which will do this for you:

```
output.Cast<T>().ToList();
```

Comment: "Your options are either to build up your new list item-by-item using a foreach loop, or [...]"  Keep in mind that's exactly what the LINQ method is doing, it's just hiding it from you.

Answer (score 2):

If you are specializing by type, frankly generics might not be the best choice. I wonder if taking a `Type` instance, and returning non-generic `IList` would be more appropriate. However: if we use **type equality**, you can just cast it via `object`:

```
if (typeof(Category) == typeof(T))
{
    var output = ItemStoreDataManager.GetAllCategoryNames(dataAdapter);
    result = (List<T>)(object)output;
}
```

If you are fussy about the `IsAssignableFrom`, then it is much tougher; a `List<SuperCategory>` **cannot** be cast to a `List<Category>` (or the opposite). You can either create a **new** list (see Richard Ev's answer), or use `IEnumerable<Category>` (that *does* support variance).